# Flutter project Firestore data sorting

Tags: flutter, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

I have some data on my project firestore. It seems like this:

[image]

I am trying to sort this data by SKU. As you can see it is in a list. How can I give its field path to `orderBy()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to sort the document you've shown on a SKU value, since that value exists in an array field and there could be multiple values.

If you want to sort on a specific SKU value, add a **top-level** field (e.g. `skuForOrdering`) to the document and sort on that with `orderBy('skuForOrdering')`.